# Use Alarm Manager to show dialog

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, android-alarms

I don't know how to set alarm for showing `Alert Dialog` after 5 seconds for me to do something.

People who know,

Please help me,

Thanks,

*p/s : I can restart the application by using `Alarm Manager` as below.*

```
 public static void restartApplication(Context source, Context destination) {
        // Restart the application by using the way : Set alarm timer to
        // open the application again in a few seconds will be the better way
        PendingIntent mPi = PendingIntent.getActivity(source, 0, new Intent(
                new Intent(source, SplashScreen.class)), ((Activity) source)
                .getIntent().getFlags());
        AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) ((Activity) source)
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, mPi);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your `Intent` to an activity passing some parameters to it in order to show a dialog in its `onResume` methdo for example:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(source, SplashScreen.class);
myIntent.putExtra("show_dialog",true);

PendingIntent mPi = PendingIntent.getActivity(source, 0,myIntent, ((Activity) source)
            .getIntent().getFlags());
```

Hope it helps